# Yii2 - dynamic search gridView

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

i have a table with record with multiple years (2017, 2018, 2019 ect..). I need by default the gridView show the year bigger (in this example is "2019"). 
I did it this way. it's ok?

**MaintenanceController.php**

```
        $greaterYear = Maintenance::find()->select(['year'])->where(['id_type' => $id_type])->orderBy(['year' => SORT_DESC])->one();
        $searchModel->year = $greaterYear->year;

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id_type),
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
?>
```

but i need filter with others years, now i already have the link with othes years like this:

**view.php**

```
<?php echo Html::a('2017', '', ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2017']) ; ?>
```

now i need filter gridView when i click in the link of other years 
i made this "trick" using Pjax but i think this is not good, and if i hide the "year" from gridView obviously does not work.

**view.php**

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.year', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="PlanoManutencaoSearch[ano]"').val($(this).attr("id"));
        $("#w0").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

which way to implement this?

note i use this gridView in view with params in url like `this/controller/action?id_type=8`, because of this the url can not be completely changed and i need it to be possible add filter from others "attributes" (url is incremental).

**Update** add complete view file.

```
<div class="maintenance-view">

    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Filter</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php echo Html::a('2019', '', ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2019']) ; ?>
                <?php echo Html::a('2018', '', ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2018']) ; ?>
                <?php echo Html::a('2017', '', ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2017']) ; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?php echo GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,

        'columns' => [
                'year',
                ['attribute' => 'id_client',
                    'value' => function($model){
                        if (isset($model->idClient->name)) {
                            return $model->idClient->name;
                        }
                    }
                ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>

<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.year', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="PlanoManutencaoSearch[ano]"').val($(this).attr("id"));
        $("#w0").yiiGridView("applyFilter");
    });

});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

in this case i need when page load, show records in gridView with "year" = "2019" (`$greaterYear->year` (variable from controller)).
And when i click in `label` with other year (ex. "2017") the gridView only show record with year = "2017".

Comment: i am unabe to understand what you are trying to ask. are you trying to filter the records in the grid view according to any given year? or just the given link? add your complete view file

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam just the given links. I update my question, added complete view, and an explanation below.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam sorry but you understand?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually pass the searchModel filter:

**Uncomment Your filterModel***

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel, //<--- Renable....
    ...
?>
```

**Filter Link**

```
<?php
$route = '?PlanoManutencaoSearch[ano]=2019';
echo Html::a('2019', $route, ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2019']) ; 
?>
```

Comment: not. because this way always overwrite the url, in this case i explain that i have a url like `controller/action?id_type=8`, and if i have others params for search (like "id", "name" etc..) ?

Comment: What about passing another variable to the controller function (id and year filter)?

Comment: have a problem in next scenario:
1º - i make a search in advanced search by the attribute "name" the url in  `controller/action?MaintenanceSearch[name]=John`;
2º - when i click the url search by year, lost the previous url, and previous record (by name = John)..

Comment: Can you provide some url examples? So your looking to append the search filters?

Comment: Also, please update your code to reflect your changes.

Comment: yes i need  append the search filters. the url examples is : - only with year filter `controller/action?MaintenanceSearch[year]=2019` - with other filters `controller/action?MaintenanceSearch[year]=2019&MaintenanceSearch[name]=John`

Comment: Many ways to do this: you are using pjax, so use javascript/jquery to update the request variable `MaintenaceSearch` and reload the pjax view.